# How to fix reading variables with n-indices from excel through tuples?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex, opl

I am currently trying to solve a minimization-allocation problem with Cplex in which shipments need to be be either inhoused or outsourced. Each shipment has 4 indices as it is depending on the plant k it is shipped from, the distance zone l it is shipped into, the truck type c with which it needs to be shipped as well as the week j it is demanded in. The correlating price is depending on k, l, and c as well. As the data for each shipment is stored in Excel, I would like Cplex to read the data from Excel making the first 4 columns indices and the fifth one the value.

I have tried reading the data from Excel as tuples and then looping them to change to arrays. As I am a beginner, I have tried to follow this thread: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/threadTopic?id=bcaea400-c839-4f12-85bc-4750c48d68f3&ps=25
But Cplex does not recognize the fifth value as the value with which to further calculate, in my case shipments. Same goes for the prices of shipments.

```
    // Indices
{string} Plant=...;
{string} Truck=...;
{string} Zone=...;
{string} Week=...;

//Parameters


tuple Prices{
string Plant;
string Truck;
string Zone;
float cost;
}

{Prices} price=...;
float cost[Plant][Truck][Zone];

execute {
for(var x in price) cost[x.Plant][x.Truck][x.Zone]=x.cost
}

tuple DemandData{
string Plant;
string Week;
string Zone;
string Truck;
string shipments;
}

{DemandData} demand=...;
float shipments[Plant][Week][Zone][Truck];

execute {
for(var x in demand) shipments[x.Plant][x.Week][x.Zone][x.Truck]=x.shipments
}
```

As Cplex does not give an error message saying the loop is faulty but it also gives no solution as it does not allocate any value to the indices but treats it as another one (or a set of comparable values), I am getting "No solution".

Comment: After setting up `shipments` in the loop, can you please add a statement `writeln(shipments)` and see what that prints? Maybe also add `writeln(demand)` to make sure `demand` is not an empty set by accident.

Comment: Hi Daniel,
Many thanks for your comment! Indeed, the problem is solved.
Cheers, Lara

Comment: Can you please add an answer to your own question so that the question no longer appears as "open"?